# plotting multiple cylinders with known co-ordinates

Tags: plotting

How can i plot say 100 cylinders inside a cube. I have their endpoints co-ordinates and diameter,height generated through c++ code.
I need a graphical output ,how can i do that?

Comment: Your queation is not clear. When say "endpoints", do you mean the end points to the axes of the cylinder? Also, do you need help with importing the C++ generated data?

Comment: I have the end points (co-ordinates= x1,y1,z1 and x2,y2,z2) of the axis and its diameter. yes , i also need help how to import it from a visual studio- c++ code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I have to define some cylinder points

```
n=100;
pi = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2, 3}] (*n pairs off points*)
```

now create a list of cylinders

```
Graphics3D[Map[Cylinder[#, RandomReal[{0, .1}]] &, pi]]
```

[image]

That's it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I dont need random generation, I have generated it using some constraints in visual studio and stored the details of it a struct. How should i import it and how to plot it after that.   Thanks in adv

Comment: I know that you have generated the cylinder data , but you didn't provide it in your question. With my answer you now know how to plot the cylinders in Mathemathica. If you also need assistance in importing data you should post it in your question and provide sufficient information.